# Loop through array, find zero, perform action, stop

Tags: c, arrays

I am relatively new at programming, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop through an array until the counter finds zero, and when it finds zero once, performs an action and exits the loop. Here is the loop I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i<13; i++)
{
    if(pHand[i] == 0)
    {
        pHand[i] = deal(numArray);
        printf("%d\n", i);

        printHand(pHand, "Your");
    }
}
```

Currently, this loops through the array until it finds zero, calls deal(), prints the value of pHand, and then loops back through the same sequence until i=0. Please help. I am completely stumped on how to fix this.

Comment: Use `break;` after performing action.

Comment: You will use a `break;` to exit any ***single loop***, however to exit ***nested loops***, you will use the `goto` statement and corresponding label.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure your professor will love you using `goto` (sarcastic). I would advise being careful with `goto` because it's use is frowned upon by many and can make code harder to follow. Also, just a word of warning, some compilers won't let you declare your counter in the for loop like that. It's probably fine for your use, but if you need to pass this code on to someone else to compile and run, you might consider just declaring `int i;` outside the for loop and then just start the loop with `for (i = 0, ...`. It'll still run on your machine and will be safer for others as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The break statement can be used to exit an enclosing loop (e.g., a while, do-while, or for) or switch.

```
for (int i = 0; i<13; i++)
{
    if(pHand[i] == 0)
    {
        pHand[i] = deal(numArray);
        printf("%d\n", i);

        printHand(pHand, "Your");
        break;
    }
}
// code will continue executing here if the for loop condition becomes
// false (i is 13) or if the break statement is reached.
```

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression from my professor that break statements would only work in for, while, and do-while loops, and assumed that excluded if statements.

Comment: @EmmaBarrett The `break` is still inside a `for` :) (and it also works in a `switch`)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if you encountered ZERO value cell, you just call "deal" function and printf, but you don't exit the loop, your are continuing to the next iteration.
In order to exit the loop, add "break" statement in the "if" scope and you will go out the loop once you fulfill the condition.

Answer (score -1):

Some consider `break` to be harmful. I've used it plenty, but some people have issues with it. If you wanted to avoid using break, you could do the following:

```
int i = 0;
char finished = 0;

while (i < 13 && !finished)
{
    if(pHand[i] == 0)
    {
        pHand[i] = deal(numArray);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        printHand(pHand, "Your");
        finished = 1;
    }
    i++;
}
```

You could also rework it to use do-while. Some would say that this kind of solution is a little nicer, semantically.

Comment: Yeah it's great to give a reason with your down-vote rather than down voting arbitrarily for no apparent reason. This a valid response that offers a simple alternative to using break. Nothing wrong with that. Thanks for being a responsible member of society.

Comment: That wasn't my down-vote, but I do think that's a great way to solve my problem. Thanks!